# Вылетает Xcode

Tags: xcode, ide, objective-c, apple

В коде нет errors и warnings. Нажимаю кнопку Build - вылетает из Xcode.
Это проблема непостоянная. С одним и тем же кодом может вылететь, а может и не вылететь.  Xcode переустанавливал, стоит последняя версия.

Я одинок с этой проблемой или кто-то тоже с таким сталкивался?
Уже не выдерживают нервы терпеть регулярные краши. Приходится перезаходить по 10 раз, чтобы выяснить, пофиксил ошибку или нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас 10.10, то запускайте build через главное меню или хоткеем. xCode падает если нажимать на правую сторону кнопки со стрелкой.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, временами бывают досадные периоды чересчур частых падений Xcode. С такими проблемами сталкиваетесь не только Вы. Рекомендация от Apple - постарайтесь всегда держать последнюю версию Xcode и MacOSX для уменьшения вероятности подобных проблем.
От себя - Хакинтош может провоцировать падения и нестабильную работу системы и Xcode в целом.